# Mysql query multiple tables retrieve all results even null

Tags: mysql, join

I try to make this query to include all products_options_name results even if there are no related rows for the selected language in the information table.
When I run the query now, only products_propoptions are shown that have a related row for selected language in the information table.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Bas

```
SELECT PPO.products_options_name, I.information_title, PTL.information_id, 
COUNT(PPA.products_attributes_id) as amount, 
options_id FROM products_propattributes PPA 
INNER JOIN products_propoptions PPO ON PPA.options_id = PPO.products_options_id
LEFT JOIN properties_to_information PTL ON PPA.options_id = PTL.option_id   
LEFT JOIN information I ON PTL.information_id = I.information_id
WHERE PPO.language_id = 6 AND I.language_id = 6 AND PPA.products_id = 121
GROUP BY PPA.options_id ORDER BY PPA.products_options_sort_order
```

TABLE: products_propoptions

- products_options_id
- language_id
- products_options_name
- products_options_sort_order

TABLE: products_propattributes

- products_attributes_id
- products_id
- options_id
- options_values_id
- options_values_price
- price_prefix
- products_options_sort_order

TABLE: information

- information_id
- information_group_id
- information_title
- information_description
- parent_id
- sort_order
- visible
- noindex
- language_id

TABLE: properties_to_information

- properties_to_information_id
- option_id
- information_id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN?  The INNER JOIN may be causing the query to omit the resultset rows you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it..
Included LEFT OUTER JOINS with the where conditions in the join...
Thanks..
Bas

```
SELECT 
PPO.products_options_name,
PTL.lexicon_id, 
I.information_title, 
COUNT(PPA.products_attributes_id) as amount, 
options_id 
FROM products_propattributes PPA  
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_propoptions PPO ON PPA.options_id = PPO.products_options_id AND PPO.language_id = 6
LEFT OUTER JOIN  properties_to_information PTL ON PPA.options_id = PTL.option_id   
LEFT OUTER JOIN information I ON PTL.lexicon_id = I.information_id  AND I.language_id = 6
WHERE PPA.products_id = 121
GROUP BY PPA.options_id ORDER BY PPA.products_options_sort_order
```